# Relative Path for reference files

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, css, relative-path

I am developing an app in asp.net in which I am referring script and style files. My Default Page is at root and other pages are in folders. I refer these links on master page.

```
 <link href="~/Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On default page links are working fine but in other pages its not working. Provide a middle way

Comment: If the scripts folder is directly off the root, simply prefix with `/`, which means start at the root folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Page.ResolveUrl in combination with the ~ (tilde) character for identifying the web page root:

```
<script src="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Will resolve at runtime to

```
<script src="<your page root>/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Note that you can't use this in the  section of a web page, because it will throw an "The Controls collection cannot be modified" exception. You can get around this by either changing the script tag to a server control and setting the path in code-behind, or moving the script and style tags out of the header into the page body.

Comment: You also have a workaround consisting in placing the script tags inside a ContentPlaceHolder (master page). This way you will keep the script tags with relative paths working inside the head section.

Answer (score 0):

As Archer said prefix js link with '/' if your script folder is in root

```
 <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

this will work fine for nested directories as well.